# What is the best way to deal with vim plugins on multiple machines?

Tags: git, vim, plugins

What is the best way to deal with them on multiple machines? I saw something like git submodules. And there is pathogen. Some vim plugins even doesn't support pathogen. I work on multiple machines. Also in Arch-Linux you can find most plugins in the official repos. So is it good to install from there?

What is the best way?

Comment: The best way is the one that works for you. Git with or without submodules is a popular choice for versioning, you could probably use Mercurial, Bazaar or Subversion for that. Most people do the synchronizing manually but some use `cron` or even DropBox or a similar service to make it automatic. Also, asking for opinions is not accepted here.

Comment: Maybe you also find some ideas in my Vundle setup. I host it as a gist here: https://gist.github.com/mikehaertl/1612035. It's easy to deploy on new Ubuntu machines. And i can update it anytime as gists are simple git repositories.

Comment: This question is unlikely to result in a single definitive answer, so it's not a good fit for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 5):

You've already found and enumerated all the popular approaches; it's up to you to pick one that best matches *your particular* environment and style of work. Be thankful that Vim is so immensely configurable and integrates well with a variety of tools. Don't expect an authoritative answer that you can simply follow. Use your own intuition (and share your findings like others (e.g. in a blog post) once you're satisfied with your approach).

Personally, I've configured Vim to also use `~/.vim` instead of `~/vimfiles` on Windows:

```
" On Windows, also use ~/.vim instead of ~/vimfiles; this makes synchronization
" across (heterogeneous) systems easier.
if has('win32') || has('win64')
    set runtimepath=$HOME/.vim,$VIM/vimfiles,$VIMRUNTIME,$VIM/vimfiles/after,$HOME/.vim/after
endif
```

I mostly use the [Unison File Synchronizer](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) to distribute my dotfiles among about 10 different systems.

Comment: Can you share how you configure vim to use .vim on Windows ? It would relieve me of the pain of renaming the folder every time I move to a windows machine.

Comment: @XavierT.: I've added that to my answer. Be aware that if you use some kind of plugin manager (Pathogen, Vundle, etc.), the snippet probably must come before its invocation, as those also modify the runtimepath.

Comment: I did the update, it works perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: would dropbox also a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

As you found out yourself, a lot of people use a combination of git (sometimes with submodules) and [Pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen), [Vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle) or one of the many other Vim plugin managers.

I myself use Pathogen (because that was what was out there when I started), and host my configurations on github. A lot of the popular plugins are already hosting their code on github, so using submodules is really convenient, also [vim scripts](http://www.vim.org/scripts/) are mirrored on [github](https://github.com/vim-scripts/).

You can look at https://github.com/jbro/vim and let yourself be inspired.

Answer (score 0):

Generally users will have Vim plugins which can be downloaded automatically using package manager or wget from public sites or you have to download + extract manually.

So, my suggestion is to write a shell script which can automatically download and put them in a folder. Check-in this shell script as a github repository.  Any manually downloaded files can be part of another github repo .

On every machine, you just get this .sh file and execute it.  You can keep enhancing this shell script over a period of time as well.

A very good example of how emacs setup, screen setup done is available in https://github.com/startup-class/setup . It pulls dotfiles from https://github.com/startup-class/dotfiles

You can use this approach to setup your entire dev environment not just Vim/Emacs.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, using a tool like [Vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle) is great to manage plugins. Other than keep your `.vimrc` file on github, some people puts the entire `.vim` directory inside [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/), in this way you can have the complete configuration on different machines: linux, windows or mac.