# How can I use local vim setting on AWS server?

Tags: vim, amazon-ec2

Is there a faster way to edit AWS EC2 config file using my local env vimrc?

I found that it is very hard to edit file in remote server using default vim settings

Any one has good solution to make ourself better?

Comment: Being unable to use stock Vim without your config is usually not a very good sign.

Comment: Could you not put the vimrc file into your AWS home folder? I'm not familiar with AWS, but with Bluehost at least, you can create an vimrc file in your Bluehost home folder and it will stay there permanently.

Answer (score 6):

### Remote editing

I suppose you're using *ssh* to log into your AWS server and launch Vim there. An alternative is to launch Vim on your local system, and open the remote file in there, e.g. via the built-in *netrw* plugin:

```
$ vim scp://hostname/path/to/file
```

or within Vim:

```
:edit scp://hostname/path/to/file
```

### Sharing Vim configuration across machines

There are many different approaches for sharing your `.vimrc` and plugins across multiple machines. Possible solutions were recently collected at [What is the best way to deal with vim plugins on multiple machines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18073942/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-vim-plugins-on-multiple-machines)

Comment: your assumption is correct....as i need to always edit file in server side, is there a faster way to trigger from AWS side?

Comment: Your question is not very clear; what means "faster" (startup time?) and "hard to edit"?

Comment: it is hard to edit, want to make the editor like my local env setup

Comment: Ah, alright. I've added a link to various approaches for sharing your Vim configuration.